# Is it possible to make use of the CPU RAM, if i'm running of of VRAM, in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I want to train a model running on tensorflow. I have a GPU but it only has 6gb of VRAM. So i was wondering if it is possible to use some of the CPU's RAM to offload the GPU? I know it will be much slower, and i can reduce the batch size and number of layers etc. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are essentially looking for a way to use the CPU's RAM as a swap for the GPU's RAM. Unfortunately this isn't as easy to accomplish and might require some **low level** work. So if you're looking for a simple argument to add to your keras model, as far as I know there is none. Some options:

- Some **older** tensorflow APIs supported this functionality (e.g. [dynamic_rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/dynamic_rnn) - see `swap_memory` parameter). However these are now deprecated in favor of the equivalent keras layer, that to my knowledge does not support this functionality. Theoretically you could use compatibility mode to utilize this.
- You can specify what device each tensor will be loaded on **beforehand**. This isn't equivalent to swapping, but you could offload some computation to be regularly performed on the CPU. You can do this with [tf.device](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device).
- The same idea as above is often applied to loading and preprocessing the data, which is done on the CPU, while everything concerning the training ops is handled by the GPU. This is convenient because you can have a batch being loaded by the CPU at the same time that the model is being trained by the GPU. I know this is far off from what you're asking, because it requires your model to fit in the GPU entirely, however it fits in the general theme of offloading work to the CPU. This is fully supported by [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).
- Use some trickery like [gradient checkpoints](https://github.com/cybertronai/gradient-checkpointing) to reduce the memory footprint of your models (with the expense of computational speed). This does not have anything to do with offloading work to the CPU, but it could help you fit your model into memory.